Can't see the logic in VerticalPodAutoscaler behavior
I'm fiddling with VPA and created an application that incrementally increases and decreases memory utilization in order to observe how VPA behaves.
With that being said, I can't understand the logic for the VPA recommendation since it's completely unrelated to the actual memory utilization of the container.
Here is the info:
I have the following deployment file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: load-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: load-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: load-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: load-test
        image: k8s_vpa_test:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        resources:
         requests:
          cpu: "200m"
          memory: "300Mi"
         limits:
          cpu: "400m"
          memory: "1Gi"

When I check the actual usage of the resources via kubectp top pod I get very low resource utilization:
NAME                        CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
load-test-96c98fbc7-jvvn9   1m           34Mi

I've configured VPA:
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: load-test-vpa
  annotations:
    vpa-updater.k8s.io/recommendation-margin-fraction: "0.001"
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
    kind: Deployment
    name: load-test
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Auto"
  resourcePolicy:
    containerPolicies:
      - containerName: 'load-test'
        minAllowed:
          cpu: "300m"
          memory: "500Mi"
        maxAllowed:
          cpu: "2"
          memory: "5Gi"

But when I check the target recommendation via kubectl describe vpa load-test-vpa, it's target is almost 5GB of memory:
Name:         load-test-vpa
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  vpa-updater.k8s.io/recommendation-margin-fraction: 0.001
API Version:  autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
Kind:         VerticalPodAutoscaler
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-11-12T15:27:48Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    99877
  UID:                 289885b9-4489-4b2b-af3b-f24a77740e31
Spec:
  Resource Policy:
    Container Policies:
      Container Name:  load-test
      Max Allowed:
        Cpu:     2
        Memory:  5Gi
      Min Allowed:
        Cpu:     300m
        Memory:  500Mi
  Target Ref:
    API Version:  apps/v1
    Kind:         Deployment
    Name:         load-test
  Update Policy:
    Update Mode:  Auto
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2024-11-12T15:27:58Z
    Status:                True
    Type:                  RecommendationProvided
  Recommendation:
    Container Recommendations:
      Container Name:  load-test
      Lower Bound:
        Cpu:     300m
        Memory:  500Mi
      Target:
        Cpu:     300m
        Memory:  4992073454
      Uncapped Target:
        Cpu:     25m
        Memory:  4992073454
      Upper Bound:
        Cpu:     2
        Memory:  5Gi
Events:          <none>

What am I missing here?

The following site seems to have a detailed description of the VPA: https://www.kubecost.com/kubernetes-autoscaling/kubernetes-vpa/
